# How to make onClick card to move to another page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, this is code for the restaurant section, it creates and maps the restaurant cards, what I want is if the user click on one of the restaurant cards it goes to that specific restaurant page which will be on http://localhost:3001/place/ResturantName, so the user can view the restaurant with more details

can you please help me?

This is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from "../../App";
import Cards from "../../Card";

function CreateCards(resturants) {

//Handel the Music, Wifi, Partition (to transfer it from bolean form into string)
    let ifMusic;
    let ifWifi;
    let ifPartition;

    //Type1 = Music, Type2 = Wifi, Type3= Partition

    if (resturants.Type1 == true){
        ifMusic = "Music";
    }else{
        ifMusic = "No Music";
    }

    if (resturants.Type2 == true){
        ifWifi = "Wifi";
    }else{
        ifWifi = "No Wifi";
    }

    if (resturants.Type3 == true){
        ifPartition = "Partition";
    }else{
        ifPartition = "No Partition";
    }
        
    return(
        <Cards 
            key={resturants._id}
            theCardId={resturants._id}
            placeName={resturants.Name}
            stars={resturants.Rating}
            PRating={resturants.PRating}
            music= {ifMusic}
            img={resturants.icon} // need uploads file
            status={Status(resturants.OpenTime, resturants.CloseTime)}
            descreption={resturants.Description}
            wifi={ifWifi}
            partition={ifPartition}
        />
    );
}

// Check if the place is open or closed depending on the work hours
function Status (Open, Close){
    const date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    if ((Open <= hours) && (hours < Close)){
        return "Open";
    }else{
        return "Close";
    }
}



export default class Resturants extends Component {
//constructor elemnts in login
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

//intialy no data enterd // the types are the filters for each place such as music wifi etc
    this.state = {
            resturants: [],
            TypeOne: false, // handel the first type and checkbox on the page (ex Music)
            TypeTwo: false,
            TypeThree: false,
            Type4: false, // Handel the radiobox
            Type5: false,
            filteredRestraunts:[], // handel the filterd resturants cards in array
            noPlaceFound: false,
    }
    this.onChangeMusic = this.onChangeMusic.bind(this);
    this.onChangeWifi = this.onChangeWifi.bind(this);
    this.onChangePartition = this.onChangePartition.bind(this);
    this.onChangePriceRatinglow = this.onChangePriceRatinglow.bind(this);
    this.onChangePriceRatinghigh = this.onChangePriceRatinghigh.bind(this);
    this.OnClickViewPlace = this.OnClickViewPlace.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount(){
    //Get Resturants data, filteredRestraunts used for filtring and sorting the cards
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/places/sections/Resturant&Coffes')
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp)
            this.setState({
                resturants: resp.data, 
                filteredRestraunts:resp.data
        })
        // console.log(this.state.resturants)
        // console.log(this.state.filteredRestraunts)
    })
}

//========================================================//
// Filters
onChangeMusic(e){
    this.setState({TypeOne: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(e.target.checked);
    // console.log(this.state.TypeOne);
    let copy;
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Type1 === e.target.checked})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        if(this.state.TypeTwo === true ||this.state.TypeThree === true ){
            copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }else{
            copy =this.state.resturants;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }
    } 
}

onChangeWifi(e){
    this.setState({TypeTwo: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(e.target.checked);
    let copy;
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Type2 === e.target.checked})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        if(this.state.TypeOne === true ||this.state.TypeThree === true ){
            copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }else{
            copy =this.state.resturants;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }
    } 
}

onChangePartition(e){
    this.setState({TypeThree: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(e.target.checked);
    let copy;
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Type3 === e.target.checked})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        if(this.state.TypeOne === true ||this.state.TypeTwo === true ){
            copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }else{
            copy =this.state.resturants;
            this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
        }
    } 
}

//========================================================//
// Sort By
onChangePriceRatinglow(e){
    this.setState({Type4: e.target.checked})
    let copy;
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.sort((a,b) => { return a.PRating.length - b.PRating.length})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        document.getElementById('Type5').checked = false;
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.resturants;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
    }
}

onChangePriceRatinghigh(e){
    this.setState({Type5: e.target.checked})
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    let copy;
    if(e.target.checked === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.sort((a,b) => { return b.PRating.length - a.PRating.length})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        document.getElementById('Type4').checked = false;
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.resturants;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        this.setState({noPlaceFound: false})
    }
}
//========================================================//
OnClickViewPlace(resturants){
    window.location = `/place/${resturants.Name}`;
    console.log("hi");
}
//=========================================================//
render(){
    
    return(
        <div className="flexthem">
            <div className="Filters">
                <h4 className="FilterTitle">Filters</h4>
                <label className="Label1">Music
                <input className="Checkbox1" type="checkbox"  id="TypeOne"  onChange={this.onChangeMusic}></input></label>
                <label className="Label1">Wifi
                <input className="Checkbox2" type="checkbox"  id="TypeTwo"  onChange={this.onChangeWifi}></input></label>
                <label className="Label1">Partiotion
                <input className="Checkbox3" type="checkbox"  id="TypeThree"  onChange={this.onChangePartition}></input></label>
                <label className="Label2">Sort by: Price</label>
                <label className="Label3" >Lowest to heighest
                <input type="radio" className="RadioBox" id="Type4" onClick={this.onChangePriceRatinglow}></input></label>
                <label className="Label3">heighest to Lowest
                <input type="radio" className="RadioBox" id="Type5" onClick={this.onChangePriceRatinghigh}></input></label>
            </div>
            <div className="general-card" onClick={this.OnClickViewPlace(this.state.resturants)}> 
                {this.state.filteredRestraunts.map(CreateCards)}
            </div>
            <h1 className="noPlaceFound" style={{display: this.state.noPlaceFound ? 'block' : 'none' }}> No place found</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, I would suggest that you should checkout and use react-router-dom for routing in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use window.location.href = newUrl instead of window.location = newUrl in the onClick handler function.